# Unknown field(s) (...) specified for MyModel

Tags: database, django, django-models

I have been searching through solutions to this error, but for everyone else it seems to be caused by a slightly different reason.  I have a models.py that looks something like the following:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    something1 = models.IntegerField()
    something2 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    something3 = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('something1', 'something2',)
```

Say I don't actually want to use 'something3' anymore.  If I delete it, and even delete and re-sync the database, I get an error saying

Unknown field(s) (something3) specified for MyModel.

This happens, as far as I have noticed, when I save anything using

```
saveThis = MyModel(something1=x, something2=y)
saveThis.save()
```

Any ideas what is throwing this error?  I have even done a search through all documents to make sure 'something3' is not in any of them.  Here is the traceback:

```
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 92, in get_response  
    response = middleware_method(request)  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 69, in process_request  
    if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 551, in is_valid_path  
    resolve(path, urlconf)  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 440, in resolve  
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve  
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 347, in url_patterns  
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 342, in urlconf_module  
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module  
    __import__(name)  
  File "/Users/me/Sites/myproj/myproj/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myproj.views import myView1, myview2,...  
  File "/Users/me/Sites/myproj/myproj/views.py", line 4, in <module>  
    from mainapp.models import MyModel  
  File "/Users/me/Sites/myproj/myproj/mainapp/models.py", line 80, in <module>  
    class MyModelForm(ModelForm):  
  File "/Users/me/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 221, in __new__  
    raise FieldError(message)  
  FieldError: Unknown field(s) (something3) specified for MyModel
```

Comment: You have to use south for migrating database. Details: http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: @ruddra - this error occurs even after I delete the database and start over though, so it shouldn't be a problem with migration I don't think.

Comment: You need to show the exact traceback.

Comment: @ruddra - No, I still don't know what that would accomplish over starting a whole new database.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - traceback added